# using find to extra property together with map

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I want to use the es6's find, I find it really useful checking exiting object in nested loop but there's one problem with it, some time the object doesn't exist I can't chain it to get the value I wanted.

Here's an example

https://jsbin.com/waxotajeji/edit?html,js,console,output

```
const data = [
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Date"
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "Time"
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "name": "Shop"
  },
  {
    "id": 4,
    "name": "Price"
  },
  {
    "id": 5,
    "name": "Token(s)"
  },
  {
    "id": 6,
    "name": "Type"
  }
]

const sortable = {
  "data": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "sortKey": "created_at"
    },
    {
      "id": 4,
      "sortKey": "total_spent"
    }
  ]
}

data.map(o=>{
  let sortKey = sortable.data.find(o2=>o2.id===o.id).sortKey
   console.log(sortKey)
})
```

Above code won't work, I might have to do `sortable.data.find(o2=>o2.id===o.id) && sortable.data.find(o2=>o2.id===o.id).sortKey` which I think is ugly, any workaround to that?

Comment: You could try `(sortable.data.find(o2 => o2.id === o.id) || {}).sortKey`.

Comment: @Xufox great, but is it ok not to check for sortable.data? what is it's not defined? will the entire break too?

Answer (score 0):

You can declare the code inside map as a function and keep it in a different file for making the code as a clean.

```
function findInSortableData(value, index){
    let sortKey = {};
    if (sortable && sortable.data) {
        sortKey = (sortable.data.find(o2 => o2.id === value.id) || {}).sortKey;
    }
    return sortKey;
}

data.map(findInSortableData);
```